# Folder Tree - Path showing on link

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, subfolders, external-sharing, path

I've been using Office 365 SharePoint Online, and I've been having trouble while sharing a folder to someone outside my network.

I create the link with view-only privileges, however, when they open the link, they can see the path to the parent.

[image: The path is shown and can be navegated]

Is there a way to hide the path, or make it not accesible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a SharePoint OOTB functionality to show the breadcrumb to easily navigate from subfolders to folders inside document library. So you cannot hide it using OOTB.

**Workarounds**:

1. Maybe you can hide it using custom SPFx application customizer to apply CSS to the breadcrumb elements and hide them.
2. You can grant access to the targeted users only on the specific folder by using item level permissions (do not give permission on the parent folder or document library).

Comment: Thanks! Seems a good workaround, I'm pretty new to this. This helps a lot!